# How can I rank one column and have a running total of the event in a second column?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to order/count the number of times a user opens a mobile application and the number of purchases they made in the application as a running count for the user.

This is the code I am using:

```
SELECT user, type,
CASE WHEN type='session_start' OR type='iap' THEN RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY client_time) END AS rank,
CASE WHEN type='iap' THEN COUNT(product_id) OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY client_time ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) END AS RunningIAP
FROM `dataset` 
WHERE type='session_start' OR type='iap' 
LIMIT 1000
```

The output gives me the correct ranking for the number of sessions, but the running tally of the number of purchases does not work.

How can I fix this?

[image: Current results vs what I am expecting]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a conditional cumulative count.  For that, you can use `COUNTIF()` as a window function:

```
SELECT user, type,
       (CASE WHEN type IN ('session_start', 'iap')
             THEN RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY client_time)
        END) AS rank,
       (CASE WHEN type IN ('session_start', 'iap')
             THEN COUNTIF(type = 'iap') OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY client_time)
        END) AS RunningIAP
FROM `dataset` 
WHERE type IN ('session_start', 'iap')
LIMIT 1000;
```

Note that based on the outer `WHERE` clause, you can simplify this to:

```
SELECT user, type,
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY client_time) AS rank,
       COUNTIF(type = 'iap') OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY client_time) AS RunningIAP
FROM `dataset` 
WHERE type IN ('session_start', 'iap')
LIMIT 1000
```